# How PHP frameworks like Laravel/Symfony autopass class object to methods and/or constructors? e.g Request $request

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a question that may be troubling many PHP programmers.

How PHP frameworks like Laravel, Symfony, etc. autopass class object to methods and/or constructors?

For example:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        //how Request $request object is autopassed here?
    }
}
```

Do they used php built in functions like func_get_args()?

C# ASP.NET for example also can do this (autopass objects). But C# is staticly typed language, so compiler know all types that method/constructor require. You also need to explicitly register classes that will be auto injected in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs. When you have done this, C# will use reflections to correcly inject class instances (C# got all the data he need to do this).

http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/15/asp-net-5-mvc6-dependency-injection-in-6-steps/

PHP does not know types. How he can do that?

Comment: Dependency Injection

Comment: Yes, but how that exactly works? How Symfony/Laravel knows what to inject when PHP do not know type of class that will inject?

Comment: You do realise that `public function testAction(Request $request)` is identifying that the argument `$request` should be an object of type `Request`?

Comment: Do PHP store argument type somewhere? If yes - how to access that metadata? Without it, that trick is impossible. For example - in c# you can use reflections. And in PHP?

Comment: It's stored in the class code that PHP needs to execute that code, and can be read with tools like Reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Symfony there are multiple mechanisms at play for example [ArgumentResolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html) and [ParamConverters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#content_wrapper) and also the HttpKernel and Event Dispatcher.

To better understand how this works you should be familiar with the [HttpKernel](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html). Basically it will take the Request object, pass it to an event dispatcher and then some listeners will be triggered on certain events and modify the request, e.g. by adding attributes. One of the events being triggered in Symfony's cycle is responsible for [getting the controller arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#getting-the-controller-arguments). The arguments being extracted be it from the container in case of autowiring, from the request or from the session are then passed to the controller action using `call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments)`.

**So basically what Symfony does is take a request, [find out which controller and action to use](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php), [inspect the controller to check which arguments it wants and what data the request provides](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php). [If the request provided enough data to satisfy the controller's needs it will be called](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L149), if not you will get an exception.**

With Laravel and other frameworks using a Middleware-approach, like Silex, it's pretty similar but in these cases it's the Middleware enriching the request and adding attributes. In case of Silex the middleware will even use the Symfony Event Dispatcher and the same Symfony events, making the middleware easily transferable to a Symfony Event Listener. As discussed in this article: https://medium.com/@derrabus/migrating-silex-middlewares-to-symfony-4f81e8548530

Comment: And if you to know some of the details take a look at the HttpKernel::handle method as well a the ControllerResolver and ArgumentResolver.  in the end it boils down to: $response = \call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);

Comment: Yes, one of the links in the bold section references the `HttpKernel::handleRaw()` where you can exactly see how the arguments are passed to the controller on a code level. If you fully look at handle and handleRaw you can trace this process. The events are making it a little difficult to follow, but tools like xdebug will help navigate them.